# Server chmod logs

Tags: linux, logging

Is there any way I can look up logs on chmod changes to files/directories on linux?

JS files on my server last night were getting Permission Denied errors losing sales.  I'm in disagreement with how this happened with another developer and am trying to look up logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, on a standard install chmods are not logged (unless, of course, they're executed via `sudo`).  Your best bet would be an audit of `.history` and `.bash_history` files of the various accounts that have access to your system.

Comment: This command would have likely been executed via sudo because that's how we do everything.  Where can I view sudo logs?

Comment: @Webnet, on some systems a command like  `grep sudo /var/log/auth.log` should show you all the sudo usage.

Comment: Zore - you're the man, thanks.  That auth.log showed me we've had someone snooping around and it looks like they might've gotten in and messed things up.  Thanks!!!

Comment: Zore, post your question as an answer so that I can give you credit.